# Optimizing array that has many elements and different standards

Tags: c#, pseudocode

I have a function that takes in X as an argument and randomly picks an element from a 2D array.
The 2D array has thousands of elements, each of them has a different requirement on X, stored in `arr[Y][1]`.

For example,

- `arr[0]` should only be chosen when X is larger than 4. (`arr[0][1] = 4+`)
- Then `arr[33]` should only be chosen when X is between 37 and 59. (`arr[33][1] = 37!59`)
- And `arr[490]` should only be chosen when X is less than 79. (`arr[490][1] = 79-`)

  And there are many more, most with a different X requirement.

What is the best way to tackle this problem that takes the least space, and least repetition of elements?

The worst way would be storing possible choices for each X in a 2D array.  But that would cause a lot of repetition, costing too much memory.

Then, I have thought about using three arrays, separating X+ requirements, X- and X range.  But it still sounds too basic to me, is there a better way?

Comment: To clarify: can the `array[][]` values implicitly determine the condition where the value expressed by `X` is valid? When is the random selection performed? Before or after the elements of the array have been `filtered` using the value of `X` as a condition?

Comment: When X is passed into the function, a random number is generated from the beginning to the end of the array.

And arr[][] cannot give out its requirement before being accessed.

That's the method I have right now, and it doesn't not fulfill the job.
Since the randomly selected element will not fulfill the X requirement most of the time, which needing another random number to be generated.

Comment: Can you please state clearly what you want to do? So far it's unclear why you can't do whatever you want in straightforward way (thousands of elements is nothing for computer). It's also unclear why you need 2D array: your restrictions on elements only have a form of ranges, no?

Comment: I wish to pick an element from a huge list.  However, some element should be picked only when X is under certain conditions.  I wish to find a way to know which elements fulfill any given X before accessing the condition, which is the arr[ ][ ]. And to answer your second question.  I need the 2D array to store the requirement for X of that specific element.  I cannot just choose a range within the array because there will be overlapping requirements.  For example, continuing with the example above, when X is 36, arr[0] and arr[490] should be considered when randomizing, but not arr[33].

Comment: Do restrictions always have form `a < X < b` (where `a` and `b` can be absent)? In this case why not store an array of ranges (with null or some kind of infinity for absent range limit)?

Comment: Yes, and all three restrictions present within the list.  Some only `a < X`, some `X < b`, and some `a < X < b`.  There is no other type of restrictions.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.  I can read the restriction as text and figure if X fulfills the requirement.  But I don't want to pick a random from the beginning to the end of the list, and again if X is out of the picked element's range.  That would take a few dozen re-picks every time the function is called.

Comment: Why not just filter all possible elements depending on `X` you receive? I mean, you look at `X`, form an array of items which don't violate constraints for that `X` and then sample from this array? Do you want sublinear time?

Comment: I asked because it looks like a Computer learning sample. When you hash the value of a `condition`, determine which element(s) satisfy the `condition` and associate the indexed element(s) to the hash of that `condition`. Next time, you add the indexer of a previuosly unknow element that fits to the list associated with the hash, untill all possible values are associated, the original list is *learned* and doesn't need to be parsed anymore. Just check the `condition` hash. LINQ's `Except()`, `Intersect()` and similar are quite useful here.

Comment: @dyukha I just don't want to create a tmp array as large as thousands elements after looking through thousands of elements in the main array to get an output.  But that is one way to do it.  I will consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here would be what's called "accept/reject sampling": you pick a random index *i* and check if the condition on X is satisfied for that index.  If so, you return *arr[i]*.  If not, you pick another index at random and repeat until you find something.

Performance will be good so long as most conditions are satisfied for most values of *i*.  If this isn't the case -- if there are a lot of values of *X* for which only a tiny number of conditions are satisfied -- then it might make sense to try and precompute something that lets you find (or narrow down) the indices that are allowable for a given *X*.

How to do this depends on what you allow as a condition on each index.  For instance, if every condition is given by an interval like in the examples you give, you could sort the list twice, first by left endpoints and then by right endpoints.  Then determining the valid indices for a particular value of X comes down to intersecting the intervals whose left endpoint is less than or equal to X with those whose right endpoint is greater than or equal to X.

Of course if you allow conditions other than "X is in this interval" then you'd need a different algorithm.

Comment: Some X will get access to a lot of elements, some do not.  I do not want specific X needing hundreds of re-picking.  I guess the best way is to sort twice, and make everything an interval.  If X is required to be 200+ for an element, I will make it `200 < X < 2^31 - 1`.  Then sort the lists every time when the function is called.

Comment: Why not sort the lists once and cache the results?

Comment: Right, yeah, that sounds like the best way so far.  And I will check from the beginning of the sorted array every time.  It would be the best method so far.

Comment: You don't have to check from the beginning; you can do a binary search to get to the point you want.  You can manually implement a binary search on the list, or you can use the built-in SortedDictionary class in C#.

Comment: Forgot about binary search.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I applied it to my program, and it works fairly well.  Hope it won't be too much of a problem when I increase the file size.  Thanks a bunch anyway!

Answer (score 0):

While I believe that re-sampling will be the optimal solution in your case (dozens of resamplings is very cheap price to pay), here is the algorithm I would never implement in practice (since it uses very complicated datastructures and is less efficient than resampling), but with provable bounds. It requires `O(n log n)` preprocessing time, `O(n log n)` memory and `O(log n)` time for each query, where `n` is the number of elements you can potentially sample.

You store all ends of all ranges in one array (call it `ends`). E.g. in your case you have an array `[-infty, 4, 37, 59, 79, +infty]` (it may require some tuning, like adding +1 to right ends of ranges; not important now). The idea is that for any `X` we only have to determine between which ends it's located. E.g. if `X=62` is in range `[59; 79]` (I'll call such pair an **interval**). Then for each interval you store a set of all possible ranges. For your input `X` you just find the interval (using binary search) and then output a random range, corresponding to this interval.

How do you compute the corresponding set of ranges for each interval? We go from left to right in `ends` array. Let's assume we compute the set for the current interval, and go to the next one. There is some end between these interval. If it's a left end of some interval, we add the corresponding range to the new set (since we enter this range). If it's a right end, we remove the range. How do we do this in `O(log n)` time instead of `O(n)`? Immutable balanced tree sets can do this (essentially, they create new trees instead of modifying the old one).

How do you return a uniformly random range from a set? You should augment tree sets: each node should know how many nodes its subtree contains. First you sample an integer in range `[0; size(tree))`. Then you look at your root node and its children. For example, assume that you sampled integer 15, and your left child's subtree has size 10, while the right's one is 20. Then you go to the right child (since `15 >= 10`) and process it with integer 5 (since `15 - 10 = 5`). You will eventually visit a leaf, corresponding to a single range. Return this range.

Sorry if it's hard to understand. Like I said, it's not trivial approach which you would need for upper bounds in the worse case (other approaches discussed before require linear time in the worst case; resampling may run for indefinite time if there is no element satisfying restrictions). It also requires some careful handling (e.g. when some ranges have coinciding endpoints).